# Correctly packaging for /opt with dh_make

Tags: packaging, mono

I know, this has already been asked a few times, but it doesn't seem to cover my case yet.

I'm trying to package a Mono-application to run from `/opt`.

First, I tried these guides:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Mono
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/

But they don't seem to do the job.

The problem I see is that `dh_make` doesn't seem to like building packages that are installed in `/opt`. It always applies its own prefix to the path (`/usr/`) and puts the files in the usual directorys (`bin/share/lib`). But what I want is a flat layout just as I have it usually when building directly with MonoDevelop.

How can I do that with `dh_make`? do I have to create the debian/rules file manually to force installation to `/opt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packaging produced by `dh_make` should just be considered a starting point. In all but the most straight forward cases, you'll need to edit some of the files. In order to install to `/opt`, you'll need to set an install prefix. Assuming that you are using an autotools build system, your `debian/rules` file might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with cli

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- --prefix=/opt/my_program
```